# VBScript Locate user in Directory; Return results (Found or Not Found)

Tags: javascript, vbscript, wsh

I want to begin by apologizing for not including any code.  VBScript is completely out of my realm of knowledge and I have been asked to use it for a small program here at work.

The goal:  I have been asked to search part of the active directory (I am told that it is an OU in our active directory) and compare the user that is attempting to login to the computer with the OU.  If that person DOES exist in the specified OU, I need to do something.  If the person DOES NOT exist, I need to do something else.

The specifics:  I work at a hospital.  The point of this is to keep nurses from using the laptops designated for the physicians on the floors.  When a nurse badges in to said computer, if the person logging in exists in the "Physicians" OU (which is my OU), then continue with the login, else log the person out (which would be to key an F4 in Imprivata).  This being said, we use a program called Imprivata that logs the user in when they swipe their badge.  Imprivata can also perform keystrokes like keying in the user's password, clicking buttons, etc.  The Imprivata program allows for code to be written in the background in VBScript, WSH, and I believe JavaScript and then executed when a condition exists (a person logging on a computer).  Unfortunately, I know NOTHING about any of these languages.

I have been searching the web and trying different things for a week now with no luck.  In fact, I have even got close to anything working so any help would be greatly appreciated and again I apologize for the lack of code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be getting the current users OU, which can be done with

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUserName = objSysInfo.UserName
```

Now you can check if your physicians OU is part of that. That is of course not the exactly same thing as checking whether that user is in the physicians OU because there could be cases where the same username exists in both OUs. However if the same user in both OUs is something that happens you have problems either way.

After you got the users OU just do a simple string compare. I always use a little helper function for that

```
Function contains(sourceStr, checkStr)  
    contains=InStr(1, sourceStr, checkStr, vbTextCompare) > 0
End Function
```

That does nothing more than a case insensitive check if a string is substring of another. so

`contains(strUserName, "OU=Finance,OU=North America,OU=Pacific Coast,dc=fabrikam,dc=com")`

with the DN of your OU might already be enough.

If you are new to vbscript a good point to start would be the old "Hey Scripting Guy" blogs where everything is explained in a lot of detail. [This one for example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/05/12/how-can-i-determine-the-distinguished-name-of-the-ou-where-the-logged-on-user-s-user-account-resides.aspx) is about checking a user's OU.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has settings for this.

> Allow log on locally
>
> This logon right determines which users can interactively log on to this computer. Logons initiated by pressing CTRL+ALT+DEL sequence on the attached keyboard requires the user to have this logon right. Additionally this logon right may be required by some service or administrative applications that can log on users. If you define this policy for a user or group, you must also give the Administrators group this right.
>
> Default on workstations and servers: 
>   Administrators
>   Backup Operators
>   Users.
>
> Default on domain controllers: 
>   Account Operators
>   Administrators
>   Backup Operators
>   Print Operators
>   Server Operators.